# Optimally approximating the sign function by functions with compactly supported Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, approximation-theory

I'm looking for a systematic way to approximate the sign function

$$sgn(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\geq 0\\-1&\text{ if }x<0,\end{cases}$$

by functions $f$ whose (distributional) Fourier transforms $\hat{f}$ are compactly supported.

More precisely, let us fix some $\epsilon$ small. Then I am interested in odd, continuous $f$ such that:

- $\text{supp}{\hat{f}}\subseteq[-\pi,\pi];$
- there exists some $a_f>0$ such that $|f^2(x)-1|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x|\geq a_f$.

**Goal:** I am looking for a "best" $f$ in the sense $a_f$ is as small as possible.

I figured that one way to do this would to be to look at convolutions $f=a*sgn$ where $a$ is a function that satisfies $\int_\mathbb{R} a(s)\,ds=1$ and $\text{supp }{\hat{a}}\subseteq[-\pi,\pi]$. For example, we could take

1. $a_1(s)=\dfrac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi s}$; or
2. $a_2(s)=\left(\dfrac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi s}\right)^2,$

where the Fourier transforms of $a_1$ and $a_2$ are a rectangular and a triangle pulse respectively.

Doing some numerical experiments, I find that for the choice $\epsilon=0.05$, $a_2$ is "better" than $a_1$ by the above criterion.

**Question:** Is there a more systematic way to find better (or a best) $f$? References that deal with this type of problem would also be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you want a family of functions parameterized by some parameter k. How about $$y=\frac{e^{2k}x}{\sqrt{e^kx^2+1}}$$

Comment: You should maybe work with the Heaviside function, a close cousin of sign function...

Comment: Have a look at the dsp "branch" of Stack Exchange, for example [see this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26406/why-is-signum-function-used-to-calculate-fourier-transform-of-unit-step-function)

Comment: @JeanMarie Ah thanks, I'll take a a look!